# reading a hand of cards and adding points

Tags: java, split, addition

I am a newbie and i am having some problems with structuring a solution to my new assignment. I cant figure out how add the points based on the number of cards in a suit which is the void,singleton and doubleton part of the question. I have posted the whole questions here. Can anyone please give me some ideas? I will be grateful.

In a card game, each player's hand is made up of 13 cards. Each hand has a total point
value determined by the number of cards that have a point value. The cards which are
worth points are the Ace (4 points), King (3 points), Queen (2 points) and Jack (1 point).
The other cards (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) have no point value. There are four of each type
of card, one in each of the four suits. The suits are called clubs (C), diamonds (D), hearts
(H), and spades (S). As well, points are assigned for each suit which has a void (3 points),
a singleton (2 points), or a doubleton (1 point). A void in a suit means that there are no
cards of that suit (e.g. a hand with no spades). A singleton in a suit means that there is
only one card in that suit (e.g. a hand with only one diamond). A doubleton in a suit
means that there are only two cards in that suit.
Write a program to read a set of thirteen cards in the form of a string, then evaluate the
number of points in the hand. The suits will appear in increasing alphabetical order.
Within each suit there will be no duplicate cards.
The output is to be the hand and the point value shown in a table form as below. Your
output should list the cards in the same order as the input. Note that 10 is represented by the
character T in both the input and the output. Input is from the keyboard, output to the
screen.

Sample session

```
Enter cards:
C258TJKD69QAHSTJA

Cards Dealt     Points
Clubs 2 5 8 T J K   4
Diamonds 6 9 Q A    6
Hearts              3
Spades T J A        5
            Total  18
```

this is what i have done so far: 
I cant figure out how to break my input into individual suits so that i can count the number of cards per suite and add to the points. Any help will be appreciated

```
  for (int i=0; i<cards.length(); i++) {
        letter= cards.substring(i,i+1);

        if (letter.equals("C")) {
            System.out.print("\nClub");
            total= total + points;
            points=0;
        }

        else if (letter.equals("D")) {
            System.out.print("\nDiamonds");
            total= total + points;
            points=0;
        }

        else if (letter.equals("H")) {
            System.out.print("\nHearts");
            total= total + points;
            points=0;
        }

        else if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
            System.out.print("\nSpades");
            total= total + points;
            points=0;
        }

        else if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("K")) {
            points=points+3;
            System.out.print(" K");
        }

        else if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            points=points+4;
            System.out.print(" A");
        }

        else if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
            points=points+2;
            System.out.print(" Q");
        }

        else if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("J")) {
            points++;
            System.out.print(" J");
        }

        else {
            System.out.print(" " + letter);
        }
    }
   total=total+points;
   System.out.println("\nGrand total\t" + total);
}
```

}
}

Comment: Do you have the code working well enough so that you can list the input cards?  Divide and conquer.  Get one part working, then the next part, then the next part.  Get the input process working, then you can worry about each output line of points, one line at a time.

Comment: To echo Gilbert (but without his finesse), you're expected to attempt to answer your own question before asking for help. Your coursework, as well as Stack Overflow, are worthless if you are just handed an answer without learning why that answer works. Please show us what code you've already written. Even your mistakes are valuable to us because then we can see where you're not understanding something.

Comment: okay let me add the code i have till now

Comment: From the code that is there it looks like the first thing in the string will be C and then you will print out Clubs and 0 points, reset the points and then start adding up points until you get to D.  But that is wrong - the cards (and points) for C come AFTER you find the C and before you find the D.

Comment: Has your coursework covered [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) yet? You can load your input into a StringBuffer and iterate over the chars. When the char matches a suit char (c, d, h, s) you know you have to change the suit without changing a point total. If the char doesn't match a suit char, then it's a value, which affects the point total for that suit (explicit hint: to keep track of points, you have clubsValue, diamondsValue, etc. and to keep track of singletons and doubletons, you increment a clubsCounter, etc.).

Comment: Nope havnt covered stringBuffer. My teacher said it will be easier if we use a subprogram to work with points

Answer (score 1):

In real life you never get as good a set of specifications as you do in a coding class.

Take the problem description and break it up into individual sentences and think about what you have to do to satisfy each and every individual sentence.

> In a card game, each player's hand is made up of 13 cards.

Ok, we're going to have to provide storage for 13 cards.  A List will probably suffice.

> Each hand has a total point value determined by the number of cards that have a point value.

Ok, we're going to have to calculate point values.  Sounds like some math will be involved.

> The cards which are worth points are the Ace (4 points), King (3 points), Queen (2 points) and Jack (1 point).  The other cards (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) have no point value.

Ok, we're going to have to associate cards with points.  A Map will probably suffice.

> There are four of each type of card, one in each of the four suits. The suits are called clubs (C), diamonds (D), hearts (H), and spades (S).

Ok, this is a deck of playing cards.  I'm familiar with a deck of playing cards.

> As well, points are assigned for each suit which has a void (3 points), a singleton (2 points), or a doubleton (1 point). A void in a suit means that there are no cards of that suit (e.g. a hand with no spades). A singleton in a suit means that there is only one card in that suit (e.g. a hand with only one diamond). A doubleton in a suit means that there are only two cards in that suit.

Whoa, this is a little more complicated.  How about I get the rest of the requirements satisfied, and then I can come back to this one.

Right now, it looks like I'll have to go through that List of cards and check for these conditions.

> Write a program to read a set of thirteen cards in the form of a string, then evaluate the number of points in the hand. The suits will appear in increasing alphabetical order. Within each suit there will be no duplicate cards.

Ok, I'm going to have a specific String input, that I'm going to have to break up into individual cards.  Maybe I should write a Card class to hold the value and the suit.

> The output is to be the hand and the point value shown in a table form as below. Your output should list the cards in the same order as the input. Note that 10 is represented by the character T in both the input and the output.

Ok, I know what the output is supposed to look like.  I'd better be careful with the T (10).  I definitely have to use a List to hold the Card instances, since I have to maintain input order.

> Input is from the keyboard, output to the screen.

I can use Scanner for the input and System.out for the output.  I know how to do that.

I can't wait to get started!

And that is how you decompose a problem into small enough steps so that you can solve the problem.

Comment: I have got it all except how to count the number of cards in a suite. Thats where i am confused

Comment: Iterate through the List, and count the Card instances with a particular suite.

Comment: But how? split the string? but how to do that since i have to split it at more than one letter. so i cant use the split.string()

Comment: You don't split the input string.  You iterate through the string with the charAt method and test each character for a C, D, H, or S (the suit).  The other characters are the card values.  I can't hold your hand throughout the coding process.  Code as much as you can, and when you get stuck on a **very specific issue**, you can post another Stack Overflow question.